# Order by numeric value SQL query in Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am displaying the top rated articles of my blog :

```
$top_articles = Post::orderBy('rating', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
```

The ratings are from 0 to 5 with decimal (example : 3.8), so I'm using a SQL column type "float":

```
Column  |   Type        |   Attributs   |   Default
rating  |   float(2,1)  |   UNSIGNED    |   3.0
```

I need to order the articles by their ratings and I think I should use "CAST" : `ORDER BY CAST(rating AS FLOAT)`

But I can't figure out how to display that in eloquent form :

```
  Post::orderBy(DB::raw("'rating' AS DECIMAL(2,1)"), 'DESC')
```

is throwing the following error `` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS DECIMAL(2,1) desc limit 5' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `posts` order by 'rating' AS DECIMAL(2,1) desc limit 5) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, )) ``

Comment: You might try quoting the entire `CAST()` so it's given to SQL along with the column: `Post::orderBy('CAST(rating AS FLOAT)', 'DESC')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CAST(expr AS type)` The `CAST()` function takes an expression of any type and produces a result value of a specified type

The type for the result can be one of the following values:

```
BINARY[(N)]

CHAR[(N)]

DATE

DATETIME

DECIMAL[(M[,D])]

SIGNED [INTEGER]

TIME

UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: ``Post::orderBy(CAST('rating_cache' AS DECIMAL(2,1)))`` still returns an error. I think it's more about the laravel way to write it.

Comment: I think you forgot `DB::raw` : `Post::orderBy(DB::raw('CAST('rating_cache' AS DECIMAL(2,1))')`